"f[a] and f[x]/.x->a produce different results. Why could this be? "
I have a question about Wolfram-Mathematica.
"f[a] and f[x]/.x->a produce different results. Why could this be? "
The code above shows different results. I want to find out the reason. Could you explain this situation to me? Can you help me?

I'm sure I've seen this before and the answer lies in details of the Evaluation chain.
